# How to make part of the embedding matrix trainable and rest part as not trainable in pytorch?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, word-embedding

**Codes are in Pytorch.**

I want part of my embedding matrix to be trainable and I want rest part to freeze weights as they are pretrained vectors.

My src_weight_matrix is the pretrained embedding matrix of dimension : [vocab_size + 4 special_tokens] **X** [emb_dim] = [49996 + 4] **X** [300]

first 49996 rows are for word in vocab and last 4 words in the vocabulary are special token i.e. [UNK], [PAD], [START], [STOP]. I have randomly initialized the embedding vectors for these 4 words.

So I want to ***train these 4 embedding weights*** and let other embedding have their own weights.

The code is as follow where all embedding weights are frozen except last 4 which is correct or not I don't know.

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, src_weights_matrix):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(config.vocab_size, config.emb_dim)
        self.embedding.load_state_dict({'weight': src_weights_matrix})
        self.embedding.weight.requires_grad = False
        self.embedding.weight[-4:, :].requires_grad = True
        init_wt_normal(self.embedding.weight)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(config.emb_dim, config.hidden_dim, num_layers=1, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        init_lstm_wt(self.lstm)
        self.W_h = nn.Linear(config.hidden_dim * 2, config.hidden_dim * 2, bias=False)
```

*Any lead is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance*

Comment: [check out this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-the-pytorch-freeze-network-in-some-layers-only-the-rest-of-the-training/7088/3)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this freezes the layer weight, what I want is some weights of embedding layer only should be trained and rest weight of the same layer should be left untouched.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924582/is-it-possible-to-freeze-only-certain-embedding-weights-in-the-embedding-layer-i/54952825) has an answer that does what you want, but its not that clean of a solution. I've searched a lot for solutions though and this is the best I could find.